# Neo4j query to get result without duplication

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The nodes in my db are as follows:

```
(u : User)-[:HAVE_DONATED{amount, txnId, timestamp}]->(p : Project)
(c : Company)-[:HAVE_DONATED{amount, txnId, timestamp}]->(p : Project)
```

An user can donate to a project multiple times and same for company. I am storing transaction id and amount in relation, is it a good practice ? Now I have to write a query which  fetch all the project in which a user have made a donation. The result should also contain the following properties along with projectId:
{projectId, totalDonation(donation made by user + companies), totalDonor(user + companies), individualContribution(individual contribution of user in this project, if user have donated multiple times then it should sum up all the donations), donationTime(if user have donated multiple times for same project then it should select the latest timestamp)}.

I have wrote the query when user or company can donate only single time. I am getting duplicate project when user/company donates multiple times. Following is the query for single donation:

```
Match (u : User {id : {userId}})-[r:HAVE_DONATED]->(p : Project) with p,r 
where p.status IN ["2", "3"] OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r2:HAVE_DONATED]->(p) WITH  
p, COUNT(distinct(c)) as donors, SUM(TOINT(r2.amount)) AS donation, 
r.createdTimeStamp as timestamp, TOINT(r.amount) as individualContribution 
return distinct {totalDonation : donation, id : p.id, title : p.title, 
totalDonors : donors, donationTimeStamp : timestamp , contribution : 
individualContribution} as project order by project.donationTimeStamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

This may suit your requirements:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 123})-[r:HAVE_DONATED]->(p:Project)
WHERE p.status IN ["2", "3"]
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r2:HAVE_DONATED]->(p)
WHERE c <> u
WITH p,
  COALESCE(COUNT(distinct(c)), 0) AS c_donors,
  COALESCE(SUM(TOINT(r2.amount)), 0) AS c_contribution,
  MAX(r.createdTimeStamp) AS i_timestamp,
  TOINT(r.amount) AS i_contribution
RETURN {
  totalDonation: c_contribution + i_contribution,
  id: p.id,
  title: p.title,
  totalDonors: c_donors + 1,
  donationTimeStamp: i_timestamp,
  contribution: i_contribution
} AS project
ORDER BY project.donationTimeStamp DESC;
```

One important improvement was the specification of the the `WHERE` clause after the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause. The `COALESCE` expressions prevent the `c_donors` and `c_contributions` values from being `NULL` if the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause fails to find a match. I assume that the `createdTimeStamp` property is either numeric (e.g., an epoch timestamp) or has a string format that is can be sorted lexically.

Comment: A Project can have donation from user but in optional match you are matching only Company, so totalDonation and totalDonors will not have contribution from users other than companies and matching user.

Comment: I have 3 nodes in my db. (u1:User)-[:HAVE_DONATED{amount:12332}]->(p1 : Project), (u2 : User)-[:HAVE_DONATED{amount:100}]->(p1:Project), (u2 : User)-[:HAVE_DONATED{amount:12344}]->(p1 : Project) . The max timestamp should be of the matching user if he/she have donated more than once and then sort according to this timestamp. I am not getting the correct result. http://postimg.org/image/3kyglgudd/ Please have a look at this url.

Comment: Please provide you complete data.

Comment: Please have a look at the following links, these contains original data and response.
http://postimg.org/image/e1skrefi9/
http://collabedit.com/hsh3f

Comment: postimg link is not working, correct one is http://img4.imagetitan.com/img.php?image=13_neo4j-data.jpeg